# Create adjacency matrix for two columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of the form:

```
index  Name_A  Name_B
  0    Adam    Ben
  1    Chris   David
  2    Adam    Chris
  3    Ben     Chris
```

And I'd like to obtain the adjacency matrix for `Name_A` and `Name_B`, ie:

```
      Adam Ben Chris David
Adam   0    1    1     0
Ben    0    0    1     0
Chris  0    0    0     1
David  0    0    0     0
```

What is the most pythonic/scaleable way of tackling this?

**EDIT:** Also, I know that if the row `Adam, Ben` is in the dataset, then at some other point, `Ben, Adam` will also be in the dataset.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by [`union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) of column and index values:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df.Name_A, df.Name_B)
print (df)
Name_B  Ben  Chris  David
Name_A                   
Adam      1      1      0
Ben       0      1      0
Chris     0      0      1

df = pd.crosstab(df.Name_A, df.Name_B)
idx = df.columns.union(df.index)
df = df.reindex(index = idx, columns=idx, fill_value=0)
print (df)
       Adam  Ben  Chris  David
Adam      0    1      1      0
Ben       0    0      1      0
Chris     0    0      0      1
David     0    0      0      0
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, I'm wondering why is it in your answer that the 3rd row, second column has a `0` rather than a `1`. I.e. the matrix should be symmetric. How could your working example be used to do that? 
I'm thinking about taking the upper triangular, transpose, and replace, but this is not very elegant

Comment: I believe because it's using an ordered matching, not unordered.