# Indexing Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index, adjacency-matrix

I have 2 pandas dataframes with names and scores.

The first dataframe is is in the form:

> df_score_1

```
        A   B   C   D   
    A   0   1   2   0   
    B   1   0   0   2   
    C   2   0   0   3   
    D   0   2   3   0
```

where

> df_score_1.index

Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],dtype='object')

The second dataframe is from a text file with three columns which does not display zeros but only positive scores (or non-zero values)

> df_score_2

```
A B 1
A C 1
A D 2
B C 5
B D 1
```

The goal is to transform df_score_2 into the form df_score_1 using pandas commands.  The original form is from a networkx output nx.to_pandas_dataframe(G) line.

I've tried multi-indexing and the index doesn't display the form I would like.  Is there an option when reading in a text file or a function to transform the dataframe after?

Comment: I think need `pivot` like `df_score_2.pivot('col1','col2','col3')`

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to merge the dataframes? or you just want them to have the same index? if you need the same index then use this:

```
l=df1.index.tolist()
df2.set_index(l, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I tried that as a previous solution and get the error "KeyError: 'A'

Answer (score 0):

crosstab and reindex are the best solutions I've found so far:

```
  df = pd.crosstab(df[0], df[1], df[2], aggfunc=sum)

  idx = df.columns.union(df.index)
  df = df.reindex(index=idx, columns = idx)
```

The output is an adjacency matrix with NaN values instead of mirrored.

Here's [a link to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806398/create-adjacency-matrix-for-two-columns-in-pandas-dataframe?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need,

```
 df_score_2.set_index(df_score_1.index,inplace=True)
```