# Cross tabulate counts between pairs of keywords per group with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a table with keywords associated with articles, looks like this:

```
article_id  keyword
1           A
1           B
1           C
2           A
2           B
2           D
3           E
3           F
3           D
```

I need to get a sort of a pivot table:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
A   -   2   1   1   0   0
B   -   -   1   1   0   0
C   -   -   -   0   0   0
D   -   -   -   -   1   1
E   -   -   -   -   -   1
F   -   -   -   -   -   -
```

It means, that the pair `(A, B)` occurs in two articles (#1 and #2), the pair `(A, C)` occurs in just one article (#1), etc.

What is the most Pythonic way to do that?

I tried Pandas pivot tables, but with no success so far. Just can't get how to connect the keywords and article ids.

This question [Create adjacency matrix for two columns in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806398/create-adjacency-matrix-for-two-columns-in-pandas-dataframe) doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `crosstab` and `dot`. You can then use `np.triu` to retain only the upper half of the matrix (everything else is set to 0).

```
u = pd.crosstab(df.article_id, df.keyword)
v = u.T.dot(u)
pd.DataFrame(np.triu(v, k=1), index=v.index.values, columns=v.columns.values)

   A  B  C  D  E  F
A  0  2  1  1  0  0
B  0  0  1  1  0  0
C  0  0  0  0  0  0
D  0  0  0  0  1  1
E  0  0  0  0  0  1
F  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

---

Alternatively, for the last step, you can set invalid values to "-1", as a better alternative to "-" for invalid values.

```
v.values[np.tril_indices_from(v)] = -1
print(v)

keyword  A  B  C  D  E  F
keyword                  
A       -1  2  1  1  0  0
B       -1 -1  1  1  0  0
C       -1 -1 -1  0  0  0
D       -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1
E       -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1
F       -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

Comment: @Dark Good question like this had been sitting without an answer for 50 minutes... I have never seen that before :)

Comment: Yeah thought it was good chance to answer, got the solution came back uff there lies a great answer already.

Comment: Also, thanks for editing the question header! Sounds much better now.

Comment: @IldarAkhmetov my pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it either using [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html)

```
df_merge = df.merge(df, on='article_id')
pd.crosstab(df_merge['keyword_x'], df_merge['keyword_y'])
```

or `merge` and [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
df_merge = df.merge(df, on='article_id')
df_merge.pivot_table('article_id', 'keyword_x', 'keyword_y', 'count', 0)
```

both resulting in

```
keyword_y  A  B  C  D  E  F
keyword_x                  
A          2  2  1  1  0  0
B          2  2  1  1  0  0
C          1  1  1  0  0  0
D          1  1  0  2  1  1
E          0  0  0  1  1  1
F          0  0  0  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `product` over groups and use for loops to increment the count i.e

```
from itertools import product 

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df['keyword'].unique(),index=df['keyword'].unique()).fillna(0)


for i in df.groupby('article_id')['keyword'].apply(lambda x : product(x,x)).values:
    for k,l in i:
        if k==l:
            df2.loc[k,l]='-'
        elif df2.loc[k,l]!=0:
            df2.loc[k,l]+=1
        else:
            df2.loc[k,l]=1

df2 = df2.where((df2=='-').cumsum().T.astype(bool),'-')

   A  B  C  D  E  F
A  -  2  1  1  0  0
B  -  -  1  1  0  0
C  -  -  -  0  0  0
D  -  -  -  -  1  1
E  -  -  -  -  -  1
F  -  -  -  -  -  -
```