# Building and adjacency matrix from 2 column pandas df

Tags: python

I am attempting to take a 2 column pandas df (where column 1 is node 1, and column 2 is node 2, thus signifying an edge between the nodes) and converting to adjacency matrix. I have followed the following code snippet from SO ([Create adjacency matrix for two columns in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806398/create-adjacency-matrix-for-two-columns-in-pandas-dataframe)), but this does not create a symmetric matrix, which is what I need. It still makes correct dimension, but help would be greatly appreciated:

Data:
[2 column df of edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roALX.png)

Code:

`df = pd.crosstab(edges_df[0], edges_df[1])`

`idx = df.columns.union(df.index)`

`df = df.reindex(index = idx, columns=idx, fill_value=0)`

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Without seeing your code, there's not much we can do.

Answer (score 1):

Following the example and the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806398/create-adjacency-matrix-for-two-columns-in-pandas-dataframe), you can simply create two crosstabs and merge them like,

Using the example there, and assume we have dataframe as follows:

```
index  Name_A  Name_B
  0    Adam    Ben
  1    Chris   David
  2    Adam    Chris
  3    Ben     Chris
```

**Code**

```
def get_adjacency_matrix(df, col1, col2):
    df = pd.crosstab(df[col1], df[col2])
    idx = df.columns.union(df.index)
    df = df.reindex(index = idx, columns=idx, fill_value=0)
    return df

a_to_b = get_adjacency_matrix(df, "Name_A", "Name_B")
b_to_a = get_adjacency_matrix(df, "Name_B", "Name_A")

symmetric_adjacency_matrix = a_to_b + b_to_a
```

**Output**

```
       Adam  Ben  Chris  David
Adam      0    1      1      0
Ben       1    0      1      0
Chris     1    1      0      1
David     0    0      1      0
```

Comment: this doesnt work for some reason, because I had code similar to this as well. the matrix ends up having values of 3 as the max value, which is obviously not correct