# mne connectivity_circle / chord diagram

Tags: python, python-3.x, chord-diagram, mne-python

I am attempting to create a chord diagram using [`plot_connectivity_circle`](https://mne.tools/mne-connectivity/dev/generated/mne_connectivity.viz.plot_connectivity_circle.html) from `mne_connectivity.viz` library.

My data is similar to the following, where `letter` and `number` represent separate nodes and `count` represents the number of connections between those nodes:

```
import random
import string
random.seed(10)

df = pd.DataFrame({'letter':[random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for x in range(20)],
                  'number':[str(random.randint(0,22)) for x in range(20)],
                  'Count':[random.randint(20,50) for x in range(20)]})
```

[image: dataframe]

The documentation for `mne` cites examples in which a square matrix of connectivity scores is used to create the chord diagram which differs from my use case.

However, it also states that a 1d matrix can be used for the connectivity scores if arrays of indices are also passed that correspond to the correct list of node names. Therefore I assume that `df.Count` can be used to represent the connectivity scores?

Given my data, I can't figure how to pass the relevant data to the `node_names` and `indices` arguments in the correct order and would appreciate some guidance please!

---

For reference, I have achieved a similar visualisation using the [`holoviews`](https://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Chord.html) library but find the options for customisation to be lacking. Code and output for that visualisation included below as an example:

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts, dim
hv.extension('bokeh')
hv.output(size=350)

nodes = list(set(df['letter'].tolist() + df['number'].tolist()))
nodes = hv.Dataset(pd.DataFrame(nodes, columns=['node']))

chord = hv.Chord((df, nodes))
chord.opts(
    opts.Chord( 
               labels = 'node', label_text_font_size='12pt', 
               node_color='node', node_cmap='Category20', node_size=10, 
               edge_color='number', edge_cmap='Category20', edge_alpha=0.9, edge_line_width=1)
)
```

[image: example_viz]

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I have found an acceptable solution to this issue.

I returned to the original data (the above was the result of `groupby` and `count` to get `df.Count` values) and used `crosstab()` to generate a dataframe containing the connectivity scores. I referred to the answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806398/create-adjacency-matrix-for-two-columns-in-pandas-dataframe) for direction

I then transformed the result to an adjacency matrix using `to_numpy()` which could be passed to the `con` argument for `plot_connectivity_circle()`.

A list of the columns from  the `crosstab()` can then be passed to the `node_names` argument.

I don't have time to post a working example of my code right now but will hopefully find time later.

**If anyone knowledgeable in the use of `mne` and `plot_connectivity_cirlce` can help answer the original question given the data in the form described in the original post, I'd be very interested to learn how it is done!**